# CreateProcess function fails to launch an application completely

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I have two application. I will just call them A and B. I have access to the code of application A.
I want to launch the applicaiton B and open a file in that application from A. I am using 
`CreateProcess` method to acheive it. But the application B is not getting opened completely.
I am not sure whether there are any common dlls or other dependencies between these two applications.

The code that I use to open the applicaiton B form A is:

```
    std::wstring appBPath(L"C:\\B.exe");
    std::wstring filePath(L"C:\\file.pdf");
    std::wstring cmdLineCommand =  L"\"" + appBPath+ L"\" \"" + filePath + L"\"";
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    // set the size of the structures
    SecureZeroMemory( &startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo) );
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    SecureZeroMemory( &processInfo, sizeof(processInfo) );
    CreateProcess( NULL,    // No module name (use command line)
        &cmdLineCommand[0],     // Command line
        NULL,                   // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,                   // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,                  // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,     // New process has a new console
        NULL,                   // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,                   // Use parent's starting directory
        &startupInfo,           // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &processInfo );         // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

The exe file starts to load but it gets stuck during the initialisation. But, the application B doesn't terminate.
It goes to some inconsistent state. This issue is happens only only for application A that's installed from it's installer. 
It doesn't occur when I run the release or debug build. For the release and debug build we are using `VC10`. But for installer
 build we use `VC12`. I am not sure on the compiler optimization that are there in place for the installer build.

The `CreateProcess` function returns success.

Thread state of the application B from process explorer:
[image]

Comment: Do you find B in task manager? What does B look like? Is it waiting for A to do something more? ProcessExplorer can show you the state of all threads in B.

Comment: @user877329 B is present in task manager list. I have added the state of the threads in application B

Comment: @user877329 Found the cause of the issue. Application B is making use of an environment variable and A was setting the variable to some different value. And B was inherting that environment block from A. I think I will have to do something with the lpEnvironment variable of CreateProcess